# Unable to play flutter audio in chrome

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am new to flutter and i am trying create a Xylophone using flutter.I am using VS code and I use chrome to run my app. I am unable to play the sound in chrome.I am getting an error message and I couldn't figure it out.

```
Error: NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:62410/dart_sdk.js:5054:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:62410/dart_sdk.js:37670:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:62410/dart_sdk.js:37666:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:62410/dart_sdk.js:37526:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:62410/dart_sdk.js:37532:13)
at http://localhost:62410/dart_sdk.js:33303:9
```

Here's my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final player = AudioCache();
                player.play('assets_note1.wav');
              },
              child: Text('Click Me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP6J9)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3B6F.png).png

Try this it works for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30694522)